# Which fighter has the right stance?

Tags: history

Here is the text we are transcribing:

> Item schickh dich also Inn das Prechfennster. stand mit deinnem rechten fuosz vor. vnd halt dein gehultz vor deinem haupt. das dein daumen vnnden stee. den ort Inn der hoche. auf dein rechte seiten. vnnd sich mit deinnem angesicht zwischen deinnen Armen hinnausz. auf den Mann. verfall auff dein rechte seiten mit dem. schwert. trit mit deinnem Linncken fuosz hinnein. vnnd haw Im gwaltig zu dem kopff.
>
> [ … some fighting techniques ]

I assume:

prechfenster == sprech fenster == "talking window"

gehulz == sword's hilt

ort    == sword's tip

Here is the picture:

[image]

Which fighter adapts this guard correctly?

Comment: The tag is wrong. This is Early New High German, not OHG.

Comment: [Here](https://elegant-weapon.blogspot.com/2015/02/episode-23-sprechfenster.html) is more detail regarding the *Prechfenster* (in English)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One important detail: [*prechfenster*](http://wiki.scholarvictoria.com/index.php/Brechfenster) = Brechfenster – breaking window (where you can break in) / Stretched analogy being ['speaking window'](https://elegant-weapon.blogspot.com/2015/02/episode-23-sprechfenster.html). But it's really more like the 'strike zone'; perhaps better compared with the concept in [baseball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strike_zone).

> The break-window is described in Mair and Meyer as being a guard quite similar to Tag and used when "under" the sword of the opponent. From the depiction in Mair, we se that the guard protects above the head in a similar way to Kron
> Meyer includes several techniques from Brechfenster, typically contending with attacks that befall us when we stand in this guard, including attacks to the hands/fingers, and to the exposed openings and arms.
> The counter-techniques are typically based on use of the Zwerch from the guard as a kind of *Absetzen* movement.
> The figure on the left below stands in Mair's "Break Window":

That gives:

> It happens like this in the Prechfennster (Speaking Window)[sic!]: stand with your right foot forward and hold your hilt in front of your head such that your thumbs are underneath, the point is high on your right side, and you look out at the opponent between your arms (as in left side of illustration). Drop the sword down on your right side as you step in with your left foot and strike him powerfully to the head.
>
> If he strikes high towards you like this and you likewise lie in the Prechfennster and stand with the left foot forward, then displace the strike with your long edge with crossed arms as you follow outward with your right foot. Then drop the short edge down and strike on the left side of his head.
>
> [Paulus Hector Mair](https://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Paulus_Hector_Mair)

As the one to the left has his right foot in front, he is the one you seem to be looking for, as already noted.

Comment: Brechfenster klingt für mich mehr nach einer Notfall-luke, wenn man es nicht mehr bis zur Toilette schafft :D